# Hello everyone, how do i play video in kivy at screen manager i tried but couldn't

Tags: python, kivy

imports:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.video import Video
```

```
kv = '''

<V>
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        padding: 20
        orientation: "vertical"
        width: root.width,root.height
        Button:
            text: " [Login-Screen] "
            background_color: (1,1,1,1)
            color: (1,0,0,1)
            bold: True
            font_size: 17
            size_hint: (None,None)
            width: 200
            height: 50
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "Login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"




<Login>
    ben: benName.text
    pw: passwort.text
    knopf: btn
    knopff: btnn
 
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width,root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Username"
                font_size: 25
            TextInput:
                id: benName
                multiline: False
                font_size: 30
            Label:
                text: "Password"
                font_size: 25
                bold: True
            TextInput:
                password: True
                id: passwort
                multiline: False
                font_size: 40
        Button:
            size_hint: (1.,1.10)
            text:" Start "
            id: btn
            font_size: 40
            on_release:

        Button:
            size_hint: (1.,1.10)
            text: " Exit "
            id: btnn
            font_size: 40
            on_release: app.stop()



'''
```

`MyApp` class:

```
class Login(Screen):
    ben = StringProperty()
    pw = StringProperty()
    knopf = ObjectProperty()


class MyApp(App):
    Builder.load_string(kv)
 
    def build(self):
        ms = ScreenManager()
        ms.add_widget(V(name='V'))
        ms.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
        self.title = "MyApp"
        return ms




class V(Screen):
    def logo(self):
        video = Video(source='loding_4K.mp4')
        video.state='play'
        video.options = {'eos': 'loop'}
        video.allow_stretch=True
        return video


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Where do you call the `logo()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not calling logo() method. This is how you can do it in the kv file which is easier.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.video import Video

kv = '''

<V>
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        padding: 20
        orientation: "vertical"
        width: root.width,root.height
        Video:
            source: "loding_4K.mp4"
            state: "play"
            options: {'eos': 'loop'}
            allow_stretch: True
        Button:
            text: " [Login-Screen] "
            background_color: (1,1,1,1)
            color: (1,0,0,1)
            bold: True
            font_size: 17
            size_hint: (None,None)
            width: 200
            height: 50
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "Login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"




<Login>
    ben: benName.text
    pw: passwort.text
    knopf: btn
    knopff: btnn
 
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width,root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Username"
                font_size: 25
            TextInput:
                id: benName
                multiline: False
                font_size: 30
            Label:
                text: "Password"
                font_size: 25
                bold: True
            TextInput:
                password: True
                id: passwort
                multiline: False
                font_size: 40
        Button:
            size_hint: (1.,1.10)
            text:" Start "
            id: btn
            font_size: 40
            on_release:

        Button:
            size_hint: (1.,1.10)
            text: " Exit "
            id: btnn
            font_size: 40
            on_release: app.stop()



'''


class Login(Screen):
    ben = StringProperty()
    pw = StringProperty()
    knopf = ObjectProperty()


class MyApp(App):
    Builder.load_string(kv)
 
    def build(self):
        ms = ScreenManager()
        ms.add_widget(V(name='V'))
        ms.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
        self.title = "MyApp"
        return ms




class V(Screen):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much